# C# Crystal Report: Unable to convert to pdf. Keeps saying Null Exception

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am able to load my crystal report but when I try to export to pdf it gives me a null exception error. I dont know where the error is. All my dlls are loaded and I am running the 64 bit runtime [ tried the 32 bit as well.

```
this.cryRpt = new ReportDocument();    
this.cryRpt.Load(@"C:\Users\Name\Desktop\report.rpt");
DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
PdfRtfWordFormatOptions CrFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = @"C:\profiles\Name\Desktop\pdfs\" + line + ".pdf";
ExportOptions expr_71 = this.cryRpt.ExportOptions;                    
expr_71.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
expr_71.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
expr_71.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;
expr_71.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;
this.cryRpt.Export(); // Here it gives me an error
```

[image]

Comment: You need a connection string and Command text (query).  The reqContext is probably null.  Are you using Entity with classes?  Did you do a query to fill the Entity classes?  Is your connection string setup properly (https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/rpcry/using-crystal-reports-to-connect-to-a-data-sourc.html)?

Comment: hi jdweng, yes, sorry I didnt include that bit. the code connects to the database.

Comment: You need to verify that reqContext is not null.